# Recreate dismiss animation in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, animation, dismiss

In my application I basically have 3 VC`s. VC 1 is the Homescreen. Over VC 2 you get to VC 3. And here is my problem. I want to dismiss VC 3 and end up at VC 1. 
At first I tried it with:

```
self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```

But obviously this doesn`t work because than you end up at VC 2.

Then I tried:

```
performSegue(withIdentifier: "Identifier123456789", sender: self)
```

But then obviously there is no animation.

Now my question:

1. Is there a way to define to which VC it should be dismissed, or
2. Is there a way to recreate the dismiss-animation.

[image: Explanation of Storyboard]

Comment: Are the VCs inside UINavigationController?

Comment: I`ve added a picture of the structure of my storyboard

Comment: @rbaldwind Thank you very much! It works brilliantly.